# Convert a String to binary sequence in C# with zero padding when not 8 bits of char

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, char, ascii

I use this method which I saw in one of the questions to convert ascii to binary string:

```
public string GetBits(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

But, If the input is something like the message bellow which contains chars like 'space' or others:

```
"Hello, How are you?"
```

The above method is building a sequence of 6 or 7 bit. 
When I try to decode the long sequence(which I know every 8 bit is a character) I get a big problem that part of the message chars are 6 or 7 or 8 bit and everything is mixed up.
How can I improve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
public string GetBits(string input)
{
    return string.Concat(input.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
}
```

Comment: Won't this return `000000x0` for input 0?

Comment: @CodeCaster - a `"0"`-String leads to `"00110000"`

Comment: I don't mean a "0" string, but a string consisting of a single `0` char. Edit: nevermind, I looked at the wrong docs and though this printed `0x(bits)`, but the `0x` part didn't come from `Convert.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is leading zeros. If you want to return 8 bits for every character, then you have to add leading zeros. I used PadLeft in your case.

```
public string GetBits(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```